# My list of number doesn't print on the screen, why?

Tags: c, list, pointers

I'm not an English native speaker. If you see any error, please correct me.

Right now coding in C and I currently have to create list using pointer and structure. But I can't change the way I called the procedure and function. As I should be able to change the header with another one who used list as an array.

When I call the program, I create the list, I try to display the list, but it doesn't write anything, only this: `process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`.

I'm currently trying to debug. But here is the header:

```c
#ifndef LISTEV2_H_INCLUDED
#define LISTEV2_H_INCLUDED
#define MAX_LISTE 200

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Entier Entier;
struct Entier{
    int valeur;
    int pos;
    struct Entier *suivant;
};

typedef struct Liste Liste;
struct Liste{
    struct Entier *premier;
};

void listeVide(Liste *liste){
    Entier *entier = malloc(sizeof(struct Entier));
    liste = malloc(sizeof(struct Liste));

    if(&liste == NULL || entier == NULL){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    entier->pos = 0;
    entier->suivant = NULL;
    liste->premier = entier;
}

void inserer(Liste *liste, int pos, int val){
    Entier *nouveau = malloc(sizeof(struct Entier));

    if(liste == NULL){
        listeVide(liste);
    }

    if(nouveau == NULL){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    nouveau->valeur = val;
    nouveau->pos = pos;
    nouveau->suivant = liste->premier;
    liste->premier = nouveau;
}

void supprimer(Liste *liste, int pos){
    if(liste == NULL){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(liste->premier != NULL){
        Entier *entier = liste->premier;

        while(entier->suivant->suivant->pos != pos){
            if(entier->suivant->suivant->pos != pos){
                entier= entier->suivant;
            }else{
                Entier *aSupprimer = entier->suivant->suivant;
                entier->suivant = entier->suivant->suivant->suivant;
                free(aSupprimer);
            }
        }
    }
}

int longueur(Liste liste){
    Entier *entier = liste.premier;
    int compteur = 0;

    while(entier != NULL){
        compteur++;
        entier = entier->suivant;
    }

    return compteur;
}

int ieme(Liste liste, int pos){
    Entier *entier = liste.premier;
    int valeur;

    while(entier->pos != pos){//The debugger indicate this line
        entier = entier->suivant;
    }
    valeur = entier->valeur;

    return valeur;
}

#endif // LISTEV2_H_INCLUDED
```

I can't alter the functions' call.

Here my second header who corresponds to the application level of my app. As I have said earlier I can't modify it.

```c
#ifndef APPLICATION_H_INCLUDED
#define APPLICATION_H_INCLUDED
#include "listeV2.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void supp_occur(Liste* l, int val){
    int element;
    int lg = longueur(*l);
    int i;

    for(i = 1; i <= lg; i++){
        element = ieme(*l, i);
        if(element == val){
            supprimer(l, i);
        }
    }
}

int nb_occur(Liste l, int val){
    int element;
    int i;
    int compteur = 0;
    int lg = longueur(l);

    for(i = 1; i <= lg; i++){
        element = ieme(l, i);
        if(element == val){
            compteur++;
        }
    }

    return compteur;
}

void ajout(Liste* l){
    int val;
    int pos = longueur(*l);

    do{
        pos++;
        printf("\tSaissisez un entier positif non nul.\n");
        printf("\tOu un nombre inferieur ou egale a zero pour quitter.\n\t");
        scanf("%d", &val);
        printf("\n");

        if(val > 0){
            inserer(l, pos, val);

        }
    }while(val > 0 && pos <= MAX_LISTE);
}

void afficheInverse(Liste l){
    int i;
    int j = 1;
    int val;
    int taille = longueur(l);

    for(i = taille; i > 0; i--){
        val = ieme(l, i);
        printf("\t\tn°%d: %d", i, val);

        if((j%5) == 0){
            printf("\n");
        }
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void affiche(Liste l){
    int i;
    int j = 1;
    int val;
    int taille = longueur(l);

    for(i = 1; i <= taille; i++){
        val = ieme(l, i);
        printf("\t\tn°%d: %d", i, val);

        if((j%5) == 0){
            printf("\n");
        }
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

#endif // APPLICATION_H_INCLUDED
```

Here is my main:

```c
#include "application.h"
#include "listeV2.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void afficheMenu();

int main(){
    //Déclaration des variables
    Liste l;
    int choix;
    int pos;
    int val;
    int nbr;
    int taille;

    //Initialisation de la taille
    l = listeVide();

    //Affichage de l'entête et du Menu

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n");
    printf("\t|...................................... .Bienvenue sur LISTE ENTIER......................................|\n");
    printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n");
    printf("\n");
    afficheMenu();

    do{
        printf("\t|..Saisissez votre choix:................................................................................|\n\t");
        scanf("%d", &choix);
        system("cls");

        switch(choix){
            case 0:
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n");
                printf("\t                     AU REVOIR.\n");
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n\n");
                break;

            case 1:
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n");
                printf("\t|                    MENU 1: Créer ou ajouter des entiers dans la liste.                                 |\n");
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n\n");
                taille = longueur(l);

                if(taille < MAX_LISTE){
                    ajout(&l);
                    printf("\tL'ajout a été prise en compte et la liste a été sauvegardée....\n");
                }else{
                    printf("\tLa liste est pleine.\n\n");
                }

                afficheMenu();
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n");
                printf("\t|                    MENU 2: Supprimer un entier de la liste.                                            |\n");
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n\n");
                taille = longueur(l);

                if(taille != 0){
                    printf("\tDonnez la position de la valeur que vous voulez supprimer.\n");
                    scanf("\t%d", &pos);
                    supprimer(&l, pos);
                    printf("\tLa suppression a été prise en compte et la liste a été sauvegardée...");
                }else{
                    printf("\tLa liste est vide.\n");
                }

                afficheMenu();
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n");
                printf("\t                  MENU 3: Supprimer toutes les occurences d'un entier dans la liste.                     |\n");
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n\n");
                taille = longueur(l);

                if(taille != 0){
                    printf("\tDonnez l'entier à supprimer.\n\t");
                    scanf("%d", &val);
                    supp_occur(&l, val);
                    printf("\tLes suppressions ont été prises en compte et la liste a été sauvergardée...");
                }else{
                    printf("\tLa liste est vide.\n");
                }
                afficheMenu();
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n");
                printf("\t|                    MENU 4: Compter le nombre d'occurence d'un entier dans la liste.                    |\n");
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n\n");

                taille = longueur(l);

                if(taille != 0){
                    printf("\tDonnez l'entier dont vous voulez savoir les occurences.\n\t");
                    scanf("%d", &val);
                    nbr = nb_occur(l,val);
                    printf("\tLa valeur %d apparait %d fois dans la liste.\n", val, nbr);
                }else{
                    printf("\tLa liste est vide.\n");
                }

                afficheMenu();
                break;

            case 5:
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n");
                printf("\t|                    MENU 5: Afficher la liste des entiers du premier au dernier élément de la liste.    |\n");
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n\n");

                taille = longueur(l);

                if(taille != 0){
                    affiche(l);
                }else{
                    printf("\tLa liste est vide.\n");
                }
                afficheMenu();
                break;

            case 6:
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n");
                printf("\t|                    MENU 6: Afficher la liste des entiers du dernier au premier élément de la liste.    |\n");
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n\n");

                taille = longueur(l);

                if(taille != 0){
                    afficheInverse(l);
                }else{
                    printf("\nLa liste est vide.\n");
                }

                afficheMenu();
                break;

            case 7:
                system("cls");

                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n");
                printf("\t|                    MENU 7: Afficher la longueur de la liste.                                           |\n");
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n\n");

                taille = longueur(l);
                printf("\tLa liste contient %d entier(s).\n", taille);

                afficheMenu();
                break;

            case 8:
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n");
                printf("\t|                    MENU 8: Chercher la valeur qui est à une position.                                  |\n");
                printf("\t.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\n\n");

                taille = longueur(l);

                if(taille != 0){
                    printf("\tDonnez la position et vous aurez la valeur qui y est.\n");
                    scanf("\t%d", &pos);
                    val = ieme(l, pos);
                    printf("\tLa valeur à la position %d est %d.\n", pos, val);
                }else{
                    printf("\tLa liste est vide.\n");
                }

                afficheMenu();
                break;

            default:
                printf("\t                     ERREUR: Instruction non comprise.\n\n");
                afficheMenu();
                break;
            }
    }while(choix != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

That's all I can think to tell that will help see the problem. Please tell if more precision is needed or if you have any question.

When I'm trying to read the list in order, it worked but it still show this error `Process terminated with status -1073741819 (0 minute(s), 51 second(s))`.

Thanks.

Comment: In the `listeVide` you have the assignment `liste = malloc(sizeof(struct Liste))`. That will only modify the ***local** argument variable*. The variable you use in any call to the function will not be modified. I recommend you either *return* the list, or do some research about *emulate pass by reference in C*.

Comment: On another note, the condition `&liste == NULL` will *never* be true.

Comment: Don't put functions in your header file.  It makes no sense, and it's going to cause problems.  Put defines and declarations in your header file.  Put definitions (variables and functions) in your `.c` file.

Comment: I have change `listeVide` so it return `liste`.

Comment: Evite de coder avec des noms de variables et fonctions en francais, ç'est une mauvaise idée et dans beaucoup de cas ça pause des problemes de comprehension comme içi